# OpenMDAO v0.13: Run an assembly a single time that has an optimizer driver

Tags: optimization, openmdao

Is there a way to specify a single run of an assembly that is run with an optimizer driver from the calling script in OpenMDAO v0.13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to run the model that you are optimizing just once? I think you can do that with:

```
top.driver.run_iteration()
```

Usually though, I just comment out the lines where I added the optimizer and then run the model like normal.